# C++ - RtMidi send nothing to out ports

Tags: c++, linux, qt, midi

I'm working on a program using RtMidi to communicate with MIDI applications.

Compilation, opening input and output ports, reading input ports works as well, but when I send message with output port, nothing happens.
No exception, no message in terminal, everything seems to be ok, but other apps never receives MIDI message.

$ uname
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt7-1 (2015-03-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Audio server is ALSA 1.0.28.

$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.16.0-4-amd64.

```
MidiConnection::MidiConnection(QString Name, QObject *Object) : QThread(Object)
{
/*...*/
midiIn = new RtMidiIn(RtMidi::UNSPECIFIED, "Mecanique");
midiIn->openPort(0, Name.toStdString());

midiOut = new RtMidiOut(RtMidi::UNSPECIFIED, "Mecanique");
midiOut->openPort(0, Name.toStdString());
/*...*/
}

void MidiConnection::sendMessage(QVector<unsigned char> message)
{
std::vector<unsigned char> tempVector = message.toStdVector();
midiOut->sendMessage(&tempVector);
}
```

When I'm testing, <del>tempVector contains right bytes (which are correct about the MIDI specs)</del> (see answer below).

Comment: Have you tried to check what ports are available? http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#probing

Comment: Could use QByteArray instead of QVector<unsigned char>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: this code is absolutely correct, it was the data given to the function sendMessage() which was wrong. When execution start, a value upper than 127 was included in a vector. As result, it seems that ALSA don't listen more the connection without force to close it.

Thanks for your suggestions!